# Python: Child instance class of an instance of Parent Class

Tags: python, class, oop, python-2.7

I am new to OOPS

I want to know when a Parent Class instance `P` is initialized and I want to initialize a child class instance `C`

like

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "A created"
P = A()


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print super((B), self).__init__ # Q1: How to get "A created" from parent class?
        print self.__class__.__name__
        print super(B, self).__class__.__name__
```

Q2: Now if I create an instance `z = B()`, I want to create `z` as a sub-instance of `P` i.e. `z` should only be created if an earlier instance `P` exists. 
And the attributes of `P` should flow down to `z` w/ the data if any added to attributes.
Basically `z` should not be created if `P` is not present

similarly `y = B() iff x = A()`
Is there a way to do that?

I am doing this because I am creating a program where multiple instance would be created of the Class `A` in various context, say

```
Mathematics = A()
English = A()
Now,
Algebra = B() iff Mathematics = A()
And 
Grammar = B() iff English = A()
```

Is there a self checker to check that? I mean how is that done?

**UPDATE on Q2:** *Another way of asking that is, is there a way to check in B class while creating an instance to check for instances of A class and getting a particular instances data? 
Like in B class checking the instances made of Class A and then selecting one and getting data from that instance's attributes to the instance being created of Class B??*

Also

```
 z = B()
    <bound method B.__init__ of <__main__.B object at 0x000000000791DB38>>
    B
super #Q3: I thought it would print `A`. WHY NOT?
```

Comment: You are not calling `__init__` in the `B`. `__init__()` - you need brackets to call a function.

Comment: @Lattyware I dont get you. Here? print super(B, self).__init__

Comment: @user2290820 yes, __init__() is a function

Comment: @user2290820 If I have a function `test`, and I do `test` in Python, I just get that function object. If I do `test()` (potentially with arguments), I actually *call* the function.

Comment: @Lattyware be mindful of properties, however. `x.test` _can_ result in a function being called if you use the `@property` decorator on the `test` function or have `test = property(...)` in the body of the class. Of course, only mean people write getters that have side effects...

Comment: @JAB I'm not talking about every possible way to call a function, just what the intention was here and what was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "A created"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__() # Q1: How to get "A created" from parent class?

b = B()


--output:--
A created
```

> I want to create z as a sub-instance of P i.e. z should only be
>   created if an earlier instance P exists. And the attributes of P
>   should flow down to z w/ the data if any added to attributes.

1) Why are you calling z a 'sub-instance' of P?  You say making z a 'sub-instance' is equivalent ("i.e") to creating z only if an instance of P exists.  How so? Where does this 'sub-instance' language come from? Do you also say the integer 10 is a 'sub-instance' of 20, if 20 exists already?

2) P is not a class, so no attributes of P are going to flow anywhere.

Update2)

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, anA, age):
        super(B, self).__init__(anA.name)
        self.age = age



existingA = {}
a = A("Sally")
existingA["Sally"] = a
a = A("George")
existingA["George"] = a


x = "Sally"
if x in existingA:
    b = B(existingA[x], 30) 
    print b.name, b.age


--output:--
Sally 30
```

Comment: ignore subinstance. let me rephrase. Algebra = B() iff Mathematics = A() . Here A is some new class(not above) where it gets certain attributes from user based on mathematics.(for english they might be different in the sense dynamically attributes could be altered, but thats not the context here). What that means is I want to create Algebra = B() but then Algebra class instance should have a mechanism to check Mathematics exists as in mathematics = A(). 
Another way of saying that is, is there a way to check in B class what are the instance(s) of A class? or instances for that matter?

Answer (score 3):

You are not calling `__init__` in `B`. Using the name of the function just gives you that function object. The brackets after `__init__()` actually execute the function.

`super(B, self)` returns a class, not an object (which makes sense - a class doesn't have a superinstance, it has a superclass), so you then call `__class__` on that class, which results in the unexpected result. You use `__class__` on `self` because `self` is an instance of the class.

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print type(self).__name__
        print super(B, self).__name__
```

Note my use of `type()` over accessing `__class__` - using the built-in functions is better than accessing the magic values directly. It's more readable and allows for special functionality.

Comment: Technically, all classes are instances of (meta)class `type` (at least in Python 3) unless a metaclass parameter is supplied (`metaclass` named parameter for the class declaration in Python 3, `__metaclass__` slot in the class body for Python 2) in which case the class will be an instance of the metaclass.

Comment: (And interestingly enough, `type` is an instance of itself.)

Comment: @user2290820 That is a new question, and should be asked in a new question on SO, not edited into this one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on reading your updated Q2 and looking at your Q1 again, it sounds like you have a basic misunderstanding of classes and what they can do for you.  (This makes sense since you say you are "new to OOP".)

I am going to run afoul of terminology here unless I know which *non*-OOP languages you are familiar with, but I'll use a C example and deliberately gloss over a whole slew of issues, and claim that your `class A` is like a `struct A`, and your `class B` is just a `struct B` that *contains* an entire `struct A`:

```
struct A {
    int x, y; /* ... etc */
};
struct B {
    struct A a;
    int z;
}
```

If you make a new instance of a `B`, you can't make the *type* of its `a` member change, it's always going to be an actual `A`.  Doesn't matter if there's a `struct A2` (type *or* instance), the contents of a `B` includes exactly one `A`.

It sounds like what you want is not a *subclass* at all, but rather just an ordinary member, which (in C) is more like having a *pointer* to some other object, rather than incorporating it bodily:

```
class A1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def about(self):
        print 'I am an A1'

class A2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def about(self):
        print 'I am an A2'

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, connected_to = None):
        self.connected_to = connected_to
    def about(self):
         print 'I am a B'
         if self.connected_to is not None:
             print '... and I am connected to a %s:' % type(self.connected_to)
             self.connected_to.about() # and ask it to describe itself
         else:
             print '... and I am connected to no one!'
```

(In C, having a pointer—at least, if it's `void *`—means you can point to whatever type you need to, or to nothing at all, just as a `B` above can be connected_to `None` instead of some A1 or A2, or indeed anything as long as it has `.about()`.)

Given the above, you can then do:

```
>>> B(A1()).about()
I am a B
... and I am connected to a <class '__main__.A1'>:
I am an A1
>>> B(A2()).about()
I am a B
... and I am connected to a <class '__main__.A2'>:
I am an A2
>>> B().about()
I am a B
... and I am connected to no one!
>>>
```

and of course, you can make `B`'s `__init__` find an A1 or A2 (if one exists) on its own if passing it explicitly is not what you want.

This, of course, obscures what (sub)classes *do* do for you.  Given your example above, you might create a class `Maths(object)` and then a sub-class `Algebra(Maths)`, and maybe another sub-class `Topology(Maths)`.  Separately, you could create a class `HumanLanguage(object)` and a sub-class `English(HumanLanguage)`, and another sub-class `Russian(HumanLanguage)`.  But you would not create a sub-class `Ring(HumanLanguage)`, while `Ring(Algebra)` might make sense.

---

Edit to address Q3: in the interpreter you can see why printing `super(B, self).__class__.__name__` only prints "super".  Having done `z = B()`:

```
>>> type(z)
<class '__main__.B'>
>>> super(B, z)
<super: <class 'B'>, <B object>>
```

Invoking `super` simply gets you this special [proxy object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).  The proxy object is how instances can call "upwards" (technically, "mro"-wards); follow the links inside the Python2 docs.

Comment: Yea this object to object connection is what i am looking for.defining instances of classes that have subclasses but with data only from their instances. i hope you got what sense i am making here